# template area and auto-placement bug

Tags: css, templates, debugging, grid

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: rgb(32, 156, 88);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "img content content"
                       "side content content";
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: rgb(226, 228, 131);
  border: 1px solid rgb(41, 135, 151);
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: content;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: side;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Popup Image Slider</title>
  <script src="test.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
    <div>Six</div>
    <div>Seven</div>
    <div>Eight</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why does fifth container is only one row height? Is it some bug of autoplacement algorith or it should be like this.

Comment: you didn't define any height. It's actually taking two rows with an auto height. Add this `grid-auto-rows: 50px;` and see

Answer (score 0):

Thx Temani Afif for answer. "you didn't define any height. It's actually taking two rows with an auto height. Add this grid-auto-rows: 50px; and see"